# Make sidenav-content appear on top of sidenav

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I have a angular application where we have a material sidenav that pushes the sidenav content to the side when active. Since this sidenav is structured to be on top of the content at a HTML level from angular material themselves I cannot make anything appear "above" the sidenav that is located in the content.

What I want to achieve is to have a card that I toggle from the content that appears above both the content and the sidenav and does not care about anything just above everything. But I cant seem to make it work. It does not matter to change the z-index since the actual element itself in the HTML is below the sidenav. Cant seem to find a solution to this so asking if anyone has any suggestions?

I could of course toggle the sidenav to disappear when the card is active but I would prefer not to have to do that.

I could also make it into a dialog since this can be on top of the sidenav, but if I do this I loose contact to my services that provide the data for my view since the dialog is not located in the content part of the structure. So I would like to hear of any other suggestions.

Comment: I would use a dialog for this, your assumption that it loses connection to data and services is incorrect - you can use an injection token for static data that is passed when the dialog is created, or alternatively the dialog can contain a custom component and provide subscriptions to dynamic data, just as in any other component. There are plenty of solutions but without example code it is unclear what would be best for your use case. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of a dialog service providing a generic info dialog that can be passed data on open via an injection token:

```js
// dialog.service.ts

  export class DialogService {
    public dialog = inject(MatDialog);

    openInfoDialog(config: IDialogData): Promise<boolean> {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(InfoDialogComponent, {
            data: config,
        });

        return lastValueFrom(dialogRef.afterClosed());
    }
  }

// info-dialog.component.ts

  export class InfoDialogComponent {
    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<InfoDialogComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dialogData: IDialogData
    ) {}
 }
```

```html
<!-- info-dialog.component.html -->

<h1 mat-dialog-title [innerHTML]="dialogData.title"></h1>
<div mat-dialog-content [innerHTML]="dialogData.message"></div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button
        mat-flat-button
        color="primary"
        [mat-dialog-close]="true"
        cdkFocusInitial>
        {{ dialogData.confirmKey || 'OK' }}
    </button>
</div>
```

Now to call the `info-dialog` from anywhere in my application, as well as respond to the close event, I can use the following:

```js
// any.component.ts

    openInfoDialog(): void {
        this.dialogService
            .openInfoDialog({
                title: 'Dialog',
                message: 'Hello from info dialog',
                confirmKey: 'Yep',
            })
            .then((result) => {
                console.log('dialog closed with: ', result);
            });
    }
```

You can see from this example that by defining `IDialogData` I am able to pass in a typesafe object that provides whatever details I need to the dialog component. Realistically, it doesn't even need to be a standard dialog, we are just leveraging the dialogs ability to appear in its own top level overlay and we can pass whatever custom component we like - bear in mind that dialogs do come with a set of standard styles that you may have to override if you want to get creative.

In a more complex scenario I could pass in an ID via the injection token and then `info-dialog` component could call an API `onInit` with the passed ID to get dynamic network data.

Be aware that the code above is written for Angular and Angular Material 17. The code may change with earlier versions but the concept remains the same. Hope this helps? Any questions let me know :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and effort. It helps in the understanding of how a dialog solution could be implemented. What I am having trouble with right now though is that the card I want to display is not just a "info card dialog". But a card that slides up from the bottom and holds entire HTML content, different for each view it is used in. This is transmitted to the card component bu inserting it within its <card> html content </card> tags and recieved in the card component and placed in the right spot using ng-content. This dialog solution makes this very hard

Comment: In which case you could consider using a mat-menu, which is placed on its own overlay, can be supplied data by its trigger and can also accept x and y co-ordinates for placement. Alternatively this component may be exactly what you are looking for: https://v15.material.angular.io/components/bottom-sheet/overview - be aware that you can disable the backdrop when your sidenav is opened, this may be necessary to achieve what you want.